# React: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router> after installing latest react router dom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, django, express

I installed the latest version of `react-router-dom` which is `6.0.2` then i started getting these error, what could be the problem.
This is my App.js where i am implementing the routing functionalities

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
      <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <AuthProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute component={ProtectedPage} path="/protected" exact />
            <Route component={ServicesListing} path="/service-listings" />

          </Switch>
        </AuthProvider>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Comment: PLease if you have done this before, can you help tell me vhat exactly to do? as i am kinda lost :(

Comment: Where did you use `<Route>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap your `Switch` for a `Routes` and change your `component` prop for `element`

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
      <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <AuthProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <PrivateRoute element={<ProtectedPage />} path="/protected"/>
            <Route element={<ServicesListing />} path="/service-listings" />
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
        <Footer />
      </div>
</Router>
```